# Extension of a von Neumann algebra by a von Neumann algebra

Tags: measure-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let  $A,B,C$ be  $3$ unital  $C^*$ algebras.  Assume  that  we  have  the  following  short  exact sequence  of $C^*$-algebras:

$$0\to A\to C\to B\to 0$$

Assume  that $A,B$  are  generated by their projections. Is $C$  necessarily  generated by its  projections, too?

> Assume  that $A,B$  are  von Neumann  algebras, is $C$  necessarily a  von  Neumann  algebra, too?

Does  the  last  question has  an obvious  answer  when $A,B$ (hence $C$) are  commutative  algebras?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a short exact sequence of unital algebras. If $C \to B$ is a nontrivial surjection of unital algebras, its kernel is a nontrivial ideal of $C$, which is at best a nonunital algebra in general, and if it has a unit the map $A \to C$ won't preserve units.

Comment: @Qiaochu In the question we do not assume that $A\to C$ preserve unit.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  The  reason that we emphasize on the  word "Unital" is  that a von  neumann  algebra  is  actually  a  unital  algebra  since it is  equal  to its  double  commutant.  So  by  unital  consideration, we  do  not  assume  that  morphisms  are  unital morphism.  However in the  question we  consider abstract von Neumann  algebras the definition in page 42  of this  paper   https://dmitripavlov.org/scans/guichardet.pdf

Comment: Your first question has surely a positive answer if you can lift projections. Otherwise I have the strong feeling that this will be false. This could also be compared to real rank zero algebras.

Comment: @Andre  Thank you. Very interesting point! I had already heard about the lifting of zero divisors  but not about projections. Of course we can nit always lift projections. For example consider the obvious map $C([0, 1])\to  \mathbb{C}^2$. there  are nontrivial projections in $\mathbb{C}^2$ which do not have projection lifting?

Comment: This is true. However, the kernel will be $C_0(0,1)$ in this case, which is not generated by its priojections, hence not a counter example. If you have a counterexample to the real rank zero case, i.e. $A$ and  $B$ are real rank zero but $C$ is not, it should be possible to even choose $C$ so that it is not generated by its projections.

Comment: You would also have a counter example, if you can find a $\sigma$-unital simple C*-algebra $A$ of real rank zero such that $M(A)$ is not generated by its projections. Indeed, in that case $M(A)/A$, the corona algebra, is generated by its projections.